# Embed a form in MoinMoin

Tags: wiki

I have just started using [MoinMoin](http://moinmo.in) wiki, and would like to embed a form in a page.

Specifically a Google Search form.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?  I see that [forms are a work in progress](http://moinmo.in/MoinDev/Forms) but this seems to be geared toward webapps. It seems to me this should be fairly straightforward if I had a better handle on the different approaches with moin.

Answer (score 2):

You can include it as an [iframe](http://moinmo.in/MoinMoinTips#Including_entirely_external_HTML) but it might not be ideal. So your other choice is probably to alter the HTML generated by MoinMoin. The easiest way to do that, I think, is to create your own theme as described [here](http://moinmo.in/HelpOnThemes).